# Dataframe transform in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to transform a dataframe in Python - happy to use Pandas or NumPy if it will do the job

The orginal dataframe looks like this

```
A        B        D     E 
foo-1    bar-6    C1    11
foo-2    bar-5    C2    12
foo-3    bar-4    C1    13
foo-4    bar-3    C1    14
foo-5    bar-2    C2    15
foo-6    bar-1    C2    16
```

And I am trying to transform it into this

```
A        B        C1    C2
foo-1    bar-6    11    NAN
foo-2    bar-5    NAN   12
foo-3    bar-4    13    NAN
foo-4    bar-3    14    NAN
foo-5    bar-2    NAN   15
foo-6    bar-1    NAN   16
```

or this then I will drop cols D & E

```
A        B        D    E    C1    C2
foo-1    bar-6    C1   11   11    NAN
foo-2    bar-5    C2   12   NAN   12
foo-3    bar-4    C1   13   13    NAN
foo-4    bar-3    C1   14   14    NAN
foo-5    bar-2    C2   15   NAN   15
foo-6    bar-1    C2   16   NAN   16
```

I have tried this

```
for row in dataframe.index:
dataframe\[dataframe\[D\]\] = dataframe\[E\]
```

but I get the wrong results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pivot part of the original dataframe then join it back:

```py
out = df.join(pd.pivot(df[['D', 'E']], columns='D', values='E'))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
       A      B   D   E    C1    C2
0  foo-1  bar-6  C1  11  11.0   NaN
1  foo-2  bar-5  C2  12   NaN  12.0
2  foo-3  bar-4  C1  13  13.0   NaN
3  foo-4  bar-3  C1  14  14.0   NaN
4  foo-5  bar-2  C2  15   NaN  15.0
5  foo-6  bar-1  C2  16   NaN  16.0
```

Comment: I have been using pivot tables for other things but I did not know that it could do this type of transformation.
Thanks for the concise solution

Answer (score 1):

This question comes up a lot because it is not obvious what this operation is called.  One word for it is a [pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table).  It is also the opposite of the stack operation. So, you can use `unstack` as in the answer by @ScottBenson or the [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) method.

```
df.pivot(index=['A', 'B'], columns='D', values='E')
```

Output

```
D              C1    C2
A     B                
foo-1 bar-6  11.0   NaN
foo-2 bar-5   NaN  12.0
foo-3 bar-4  13.0   NaN
foo-4 bar-3  14.0   NaN
foo-5 bar-2   NaN  15.0
foo-6 bar-1   NaN  16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly simple solution. Let me know if you have any questions (:

```
data = {
'A': ['foo-1', 'foo-2', 'foo-3', 'foo-4', 'foo-5', 'foo-6'],
'B': ['bar-6', 'bar-5', 'bar-4', 'bar-3', 'bar-2', 'bar-1'],
'D': ['C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2'],
'E': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
column_index = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for (a,b,c) in zip(df['D'], df['E'], column_index):
    if df['D'][c] == 'C1':
        df['E'][c] = 'NAN
        df['D'][c] = b
    else:
        df['E'][c] = b
        df['D'][c] = 'NAN
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C1', 'C2']
print(df)
```

|  | A | B | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | foo-1 | bar-6 | 11 | nan |
| 1 | foo-2 | bar-5 | nan | 12 |
| 2 | foo-3 | bar-4 | 13 | nan |
| 3 | foo-4 | bar-3 | 14 | nan |
| 4 | foo-5 | bar-2 | nan | 15 |
| 5 | foo-6 | bar-1 | nan | 16 |